# Command not found when SSHing into Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ssh, login, motd

I have an issue when logging into my Ubuntu 12.04 machine via SSH. It lags for about 40 seconds after printing half of the MOTD. Then it says

```
[...]: command not found
```

and completes the login.

My MOTD reads as follows when I log in:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-35-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Sat Oct  5 20:37:30 2013 from windows
[...]: command not found
```

I looked into modifying `/etc/motd`. However, the system uses `update-motd` and I can't wrap my head around how that program works. I can't find in which file the offending missing command is in. I like the dynamis MOTD, but this lag is driving me nuts. Lil help?

My `/etc/update-motd.d/` looks like this:

```
me@server:/etc/update-motd.d$ ls -al
total 44
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 29 02:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 156 root root 12288 Oct  5 20:41 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1220 Apr 19  2012 00-header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1358 Apr 19  2012 10-help-text
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   149 Aug 22  2011 90-updates-available
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   129 Sep 30  2011 91-release-upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   142 Aug 22  2011 98-fsck-at-reboot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   144 Aug 22  2011 98-reboot-required
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1158 Apr 19  2012 99-footer
```

Thanks in advance, wonderful internet folk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `/etc/motd` is updated every 10 mins (by default) by the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d`.  See:
[UpdateMotd](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd)

The scripts are executed in order from 00 to 99 and write the output to the /etc/motd file.

Hence the file `/etc/motd` is still static and I don't think will be the cause of your problem.  Especially as the "Last Login" message is controlled by `sshd` and executed after `motd`.  You should examine your profile scripts.  Try your `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files in your home directory and look for the command that could be causing your problem.

Less likely but possible is the file `/etc/profile` which could be being executed before your individual user profile is.  Check that too if your personal profile doesn't show anything.

Comment: That did it! I found something in `~/.profile`. I installed adb years ago and removed it. There was a reference to add the adb dir to path. I guess that reference hadn't been removed. I feel pretty dumb now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :-)